# Area under curves

Tags: integration, area, curves

> Let $a$, $b$ > 0. Show that the area between the curves $y = x^a$ and $y = (1 - x)^b$ for 0 ≤ x ≤ 1 is equal to the area between $y = x^b$ and $y = (1 - x)^a. $

I created [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wr1mspphi1) demonstration, and it seems like this should hold true. I understand this can be done by integrating but I can't seem to proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Take intuition from $$\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\int_0^1 f(1-x)dx$$

Comment: I don't understand how you were able to derive this.

Comment: The area is $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\int_{r_i}^{r_{i+1}}|x^a-(1-x)^b|dx+\int_0^{r_1}|x^a-(1-x)^b|dx+\int_{r_n}^{1}|x^a-(1-x)^b|dx$$which can also be written as $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\int_{r'_i}^{r'_{i+1}}|x^b-(1-x)^a|dx+\int_0^{r'_1}|x^b-(1-x)^a|dx+\int_{r'_n}^{1}|x^b-(1-x)^a|dx$$where $r'_i=1-r_i$

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{Area} = \bigg|\int^1_0(x^a-(1-x)^b)dx\bigg| = \bigg|\int^1_0((1-x)^a-x^b)dx\bigg|$$

as, $$\int_0^af(x)dx = \int^a_0f(a-x)dx$$